# To not tell, not take, and not want

Tags: riddle

Here is a fun riddle:

> The one who makes it, tells it not. Whoever takes it, knows it not. Whoever knows it wants it not. What is it the riddle is describing?

**Please explain!**

Comment: There are so many correct answers to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it

> Counterfeit money?

Whoever makes it, tells it not.

> No one tells they are counterfeiting money.

Whoever takes it, knows it not.

> Hard to know the difference.

Whoever knows it, wants it not

> If you know it's counterfeit you probably don't want it.

Comment: Correct! It is Counterfeit Money!

Answer (score 9):

I believe the only thing distinguishing answers of the form

> [thing to be avoided]

is how well they match up with the verbs, so the answer is

> **poison** made with malicious intent.

The one who makes it, tells it not.

> The person who makes the poison might not warn others.

Whoever takes it, knows it not.

> The person who takes the poison might do so unknowingly.

Whoever knows it wants it not.

> The person who knows the poison might not want it.

Answer (score 8):

It could be...

> Intestinal gas

The one who makes it, tells it not.

> If you pass gas, you don't advertise it - this is the origin of the phrase "whoever smelt it, dealt it"

Whoever takes it, knows it not.

> No one knowingly chooses to breath this stuff in...

Whoever knows it wants it not.

> You wouldn't choose to have gas.

Ugh!

Comment: A good, and *gassy* guess but incorrect. Keep it up!

Comment: Dang. You gotta get an upvote for that lateral thinking.

Answer (score 7):

There was a similar riddle that I heard once that could mean it's

> a coffin?

The one who makes it, tells it not.

> Coffinmakers tend not to advertise very flagrantly.

Whoever takes it, knows it not.

> The man in the coffin is dead and doesn't know he has it.

Whoever knows it wants it not.

> Whoever knows it's a coffin certainly doesn't want to die.

Comment: You are on the right track. I believe this is the riddle you have the answer to: *"The one who made it didn’t want it. The one who bought it didn’t need it. The one who used it never saw it. What is it?"*. The answer to that is a *Coffin*.

Comment: Yes, that is it -- I just thought this was a variation, @Xilpex.

Answer (score 5):

If I am right, it can be a

> rumour.

Reasoning:

> It is made up by someone and would spread it by some other means . The one who receives it doesn't know it (it's a rumour). The one who knows it's a rumour doesn't want it. (It's useless for that person)

Comment: Edited in  my answer.

Comment: Hello, @Tojrah! Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (PSE)**! I see you are a new contributor to this community! I strongly advise that you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) so that you know how things work around here. As a matter of fact, you seem to know how to write a decent answer, so that part may be covered already! So, regarding questions, I suggest you head [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and above all, [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/conduct). Enjoy!! :D

Answer (score 3):

It is a

> Trojan

Whoever makes it, tells it not.

> I wouldn't tell you, would i? :P

Whoever takes it, knows it not.

> You won't know you have it

Whoever knows it, wants it not

> Who would :P

Answer (score 2):

Is it:

> Death?

The one who makes it tells it not:

> The Grim Reaper makes death happen and he tell us not of it, or where, when, how, and why.

Whoever takes it knows it not:

> Sometimes a person just dies, just like that, in the blink of an eye. They would not know it.

Whoever knows it wants it not:

> No one wants to die

This answer may be a bit of a strech, but I believe it is within theme area of the coffin answer, which we were told was close.

Comment: You're on the right track, but no.

Answer (score 1):

It is

> **Kindness**

### Because:

1. The one who makes it, tells it not.
2. Whoever takes it, knows it not.
3. Whoever knows it wants it not.